# File regex in npm replace

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match the following file formats to prefix the files with an absolute URL. The strings are part of an `index.html` file and I'm using `npm replace` to find/replace. Here are the different file names:

- favicon.ico
- main.somestringwithcharacterandletters.css
- main.somestringwithcharacterandletters.js
- somestringwithcharactersandletters.woff
- somestringwithcharactersandletter.ttf

I've tried the following regex:

```
(main\.)?(\w)+\.(css|js|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|png|ico){1}
```

This matches the last character in the filename and the extension instead of the full filename and the extension. What needs to be changed to match the full filename so I can prefix an absolute path?

Comment: Note that `{1}` is never ever useful in regex. A quantifier of 1 occurrence is the same as no quantifier

Comment: [Add another set of brackets?](https://regex101.com/r/uY8dG5)

Comment: `(\w)+` -> `(\w+)`. Instead of quantifying a group that captures the last matched value, you should quantify the pattern inside the group.

Comment: Add a `$` at the end to indicate that it should match the end part of the name no matter what intervening folders are called?

Comment: Not my issue. As you see from that regex101 it is working for me. I haven't tried it with npm replace. I can see your suggestion is more logical.

Comment: Sorry :) wrong, addressee, I was using a mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the redundant `{1}` and what is more important - move the `+` into the second capture group:

```
(main\.)?(\w+)\.(css|js|woff2?|eot|ttf|png|ico)
            ^                                  ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uQ6bR9/1).

[image]

When you set a quantifier to a group, the whole group pattern is matches repeatedly, but the contents of the group stack is constantly re-written with each subsequent match. Thus, always check what you quantify, in many situations, you want to quantify the group pattern, not the group itself (unless it is a non-capturing group, when you know nothing is captured and we use it to just group a sequence of subpatterns).